# Why are there no spaces on both sides of the equals sign in chunk headers of R Markdown templates?

Tags: r, templates, r-markdown, coding-style

In the R Markdown file that you get if you create e.g. a new R Markdown file in RStudio from the template there, you will see that parameter settings in the chunk headers are often written without spaces on the sides of the equals (`=`) sign.

In the two examples below what I mean are `include=FALSE` and `echo=FALSE`.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I quite commonly see this and IMO it does not adhere to the [infix operator suggestions](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html#infix-operators) of the tidyverse styleguide. Interestingly, we can even see the alternative infix space handling in `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)` where spaces are set.

Since all these resources more or less come out of the [posit](https://posit.co/) ecosystem I was wondering where this supposed inconsistency comes from and if there's a good reason why spaces are omitted here.

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the style in R Markdown is borrowed from Sweave (see `vignette("Sweave", package = "utils")`) and ultimately from Knuth's TeXbook.  `utils:::SweaveParseOptions` discards whitespace around the `=`, so it really is a matter of style.  (In Plain TeX, the `=` itself is optional in assignments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that it might be related that RMarkdown has been influenced by Sweave where chunk options looked like this: `<<results=hide>>=`. https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie can answer that probably more accuratly.

I can only say that in the "new RMarkdown" Quarto, the default behaviour of code chunk behave in a way you would expect from the tidyverse styleguide, ,e.g

````
```{r}
#|echo: true
x <- 2
```
````